# Spring Java Unit Testing; How do i initialise a beans property at the point of @BeforeClass?

Tags: spring, junit, javabeans

In a test class I have a static 
.
.
.

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

    //Set utility beans property 
    // Not a System property.

}
```

At this point, How do i initialize or set the property of a bean ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using XML to configure the beans?

Comment: no JavaConfig & annotations.

Comment: @Configuration
        public class configProfile {

            @Property(name="host", settable = Settable.OPTIONAL, defaultValue = "",description = "host address.")
            public String Host = "";

Comment: This is the entity I wish to set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to setup in setUpBeforeClass() method, this is impossible. But if  you just want to setup it and you're using xml configuration this is an other way.

Generally speaking, you need to create an applicationContext.test.xml which overide the applicationContext.xml. Use it in JUnit instead of applicationContext.xml

For e.g. here is your applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean name="utilBean" class="UtilBean">
        <property name="prop1" value="1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="anotherBean" class="AnotherBean">
        <property name="propAnother" value="10"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

For setting the 'prop1' with 2 in 'utilBean', you should create a new applicationContext.test.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <!-- import the original one -->
    <import resource="classpath*:applicationContext.xml" />

    <!-- Override utilBean -->
    <bean name="utilBean" class="UtilBean">
        <!-- Override prop1 value -->
        <property name="prop1" value="2"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Then in your JUnit class, use applicationContext.test.xml instead of applicationContext.xml

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:applicationContext.test.xml" })
public class JunitTest {
// your tests
}
```

Your prop1 value of utilBean is set with '2' in your JunitTest, but in your original process it will always be '1'

You can also use antoherBean in your JUnit, it's 'propAnother' value equals to 10, both in JUnit and in original process.

Sorry I didn't saw comments... In your case, override the configuration in this way:

```
@Import(ApplicationContext.class)
@Configuration
public class TestApplicationContext {
...
}
```

Then override your bean. Use this configuration class instead of the original one in your JUnitClass

Comment: Have you any references in how this is done with javaConfig as opposed to xml ? (Thanks by the way !!)

Comment: I've added the java way in the end

Answer (score 0):

In your test class declaration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTest {

 //... your tests

   @Configuration
   public static class Config {
    //your configuration for the test
   } 


} // end of test class
```